# storing a file in an already occupied location in Pig

Tags: user-defined-functions, apache-pig

It seems that Pig prevents us from reusing an output directory. In that case, I want to write a Pig UDF that will accept a filename as parameter, open the file within the UDF and append the contents to the already existing file at the location. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible, but I don't know that it's advisable.  Why not just have a new output directory?  For example, if ultimately you want all your results in `/path/to/results`, `STORE` the output of the first run into `/path/to/results/001`, the next run into `/path/to/results/002`, and so on.  This way you can easily identify bad data from any failed jobs, and if you want all of it together, you can just do `hdfs -cat /path/to/results/*/*`.

If you don't actually want to append but instead want to just replace the existing contents, you can use Pig's `RMF` shell command:

```
%DEFINE output /path/to/results
RMF $output
STORE results INTO '$output';
```